# "The App is blocked" with a Google Account that has a Monetized Youtube Account

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are currently testing an app that utilizes the YouTube API to list a Google Account's YouTube Channels and get the channel information.

We have tested this with a Non-Monetized YouTube account, and we were able to allow the app to get information from YouTube's API. However, when we tested with a Monetized YouTube Account, we are getting a "This App is Blocked" error, and unable to allow the app to get details.

[image: This is the error we are getting.]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].

Comment: Your app is not approved to access that account with the requested sensitive scopes. You will need to get approval from Google. Stackoverflow cannot help you with this problem. This link provides details on how to get approved. https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en